# CartThrob Discounts being applied incorrectly

Tags: cartthrob

I've set up a couple discounts based on quantity, for example:

Buy 2 CD's and get $4.98 off
Buy 3 CD's and get $14.97 off

Both of these are triggered by the "If order over" field. However, what seems to be happening is that all the discounts are being applied even if the order minimum is not met.

Meaning... if I have 2 CD's in the cart, BOTH discounts are being applied for a total of $19.97 off.

Anyone seen this? Is this a configuration error or a bug?

[image: 2 CD Discount]

[image: 3 CD discount]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discount option is actually *Amount off for orders over 'x' $* rather than a quantity threshold.

So, get $2 discount when your order is over $20.

Comment: Ah... yeah, that makes sense now. Seems like what I want to do is tricky.